# What's a way to refer to haunting without a negative connotation?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, synonyms

Is there a single word that refers to the idea that a spirit may persist after death and follow a person around without any negative connotations?

Some possible answers and why I think they may be unsatisfactory:

- To haunt seems to imply a malicious intent.
- To be in somebody's heart doesn't really imply an actual spiritual presence; it seems to imply memory of a person.
- To watch over somebody seems to indicate that the spirit is much more removed from the situation.
- To shadow somebody might still have negative connotations.

Also, I was hoping for a single verb if that exists. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW... you could use "visited" as in, "I'm constantly visited by my late wife"

Comment: It's a preposition but _with_ might work. _I will always be with you, even after death._

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is the concept of a familiar?

Comment: Disagree with your analysis of "watch over"; it's common to hear "watched over by a guardian angel", which implies you've been the benefited by divine intervention. Also, an example sentence would really help narrow in the choices.

Comment: "Haunting" isn't necessarily negative (e.g. haunting melody) but it's generally negative because seeing a dead person is generally disturbing. Anyway, it depends on whether the spirit is visible or invisibly observing.

Answer (score 1):

How about [indwell](https://www.google.com/search?q=indwell&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#)?

> **indwell**
>   verb
>   1. be permanently present in (someone's soul or mind); possess spiritually.

It implies more of a *union* than *accompaniment*, however. Might not be quite what you want.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was hoping, but it certainly is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

"Presence" is more noun than verb, but closer to a benevolent companion than 'haunt'
a person or thing that exists or is present in a place but is not seen.
plural noun: presences

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Lingering](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/lingering): "still existing or happening after something is completed or removed."

This is what I'd go for.
E.g. "The lingering spirit of the late Obnaxeus V. Morbaldeaux was something the tenants of the mansion had to get accustomed to."